# Вызов функции по ссылке

Tags: python, ооп, функции

В примере с ООП столкнулся с тем, что функция вызывается просто по ссылке, то есть - без круглых скобок(без передачи аргументов). И это происходит только тогда, когда этот метод(функция) вызывается в качестве аргумента.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.b = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Push me')
        self.l = QtWidgets.QLabel('I have not been clicked yet')

        h_box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        h_box.addStretch()
        h_box.addWidget(self.l)
        h_box.addStretch()

        v_box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        v_box.addWidget(self.b)
        v_box.addLayout(h_box)

        self.setLayout(v_box)
        self.setWindowTitle("Thirst winning")

        self.b.clicked.connect(self.b_click)

        self.show()

    def b_click(self):
        self.l.setText('I have been clicked')

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
a_window = Window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

С чем это связано, и можно ли где - то еще это встретить ?

Comment: Это называется ссылкой на функцию и намного чаще её можно встретить в ФП, чем в ООП.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev я знаю что это ссылка на функцию, вопрос другой был.

Comment: Если нужно в агумент передать результат работы функции функцию вызывают со скобками, если нужно использавать некоторую функцию внутри другой функции аргументу передают объект функции (без скобок).

Answer (score 4):

С чем это связано? Связано это с тем, что есть некий код, который ожидает, что некоторая функция выполняет определенный контракт. Например, `filter`. Вам достаточно передать туда функцию, которая по контракту принимает элемент последовательности и возвращает булево значение. В итоге вам не нужно писать весь код фильтрации. В питоне можно что угодно передавать, как аргумент функции и возвращать из нее. Функция, класс - без разницы, это позволяет писать более краткий и удобный код. Так же на этой возможности языка основываются декораторы. Можно ли еще где-то встретить? Да где угодно, это довольно часто используемая возможность языка, особенно во всяких библиотеках и фреймворках.

Answer (score 1):

> функция вызывается просто по ссылке, то есть - без круглых скобок(без передачи аргументов)

У вас `self.b_click` метод **не вызывается**, он просто передаётся в качестве аргумента (как любой другой объект). Если `f` имя ссылается на функцию, то `f` в исходном коде **никогда** не вызывает эту функцию в Питоне. Чтобы вызвать функцию в Питоне, следует скобки добавить: `f()`.

```
>>> print
<built-in function print>
>>> print('abc')
abc
```

В Питоне можно переопределить, что `obj.attr` делает, к примеру, `@property` позволяет произвольный код выполнить при доступе к атрибуту — это не ваш случай. У вас `self.b_click` это обычный метод: можете его передать как аргумент в функцию, вернуть в качестве возвращаемого значения, вызывать его методы (`__call__`), обращаться к атрибутам (`__name__`), поместить в список, словарь, итд — всё что вы с любым другим объектом в Питоне могли бы делать.

Answer (score 0):

Везде, где удобно. Например, удобно использовать при "партизанском патчинге", когда во время правки "на лету" можешь заменить метод объекта. 
Да и просто забавно:

```
from math import sin

def f1(x):
    return x+5

def f2(x):
    return x**2

def f3(x):
    return sin(x)

def f4(x):   
    return x*x*sin(x)  
f3=f4     #правка по горячему 

fs = [f1,f2,f3]
x = [5,6,7]
print (sum([fs[i](x[i]) for  i in range(len(fs))]))
```

Answer (score 0):

связано с тем, что в питоне, все что не является ключевым словом, это объект какого-то класса

```
def myfunc():
    print(1)

# видно что myfunc - это просто класс
print(type(myfunc))  # <class 'function'>
print(myfunc)  # <function myfunc at 0x0398D5D0>

# а значит у него есть методы
print(dir(myfunc))  # ['__annotations__', '__call__', '__class__', ...

# объект myfunc ведет себя как функция, потому что имеет метод __call__
myfunc()  # можно считать это сокращенной формой вызова myfunc.__call__
myfunc.__call__()  # тоже самое

# все "слова" используемые тут - это объекты класса
# на них можно ссылатся как obj и использовать их как угодно obj() или type(obj)
for obj in [myfunc, print, type, dir, 1, callable]:
    print(type(obj))
    if callable(obj):
        obj()
```